# Initializing select box for more than 500 select in a grid

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, ui-select2

I am using select2 DropDown inside my grid. There are more than 500 select element exists in a grid. When I initialize all this select element with select2 it is taking more than 20 seconds

```
$("select[id*='elementNameLike']").select2({
    allowClear = false;
});
```

Is there any way by which I can Improve my performance.

Comment: Could you provide some html?

Comment: Limit the size of the grid.. maybe with pagination.